# How to add a gradient for the header of a chat box?

Tags: javascript

I have this chat window and I want every time a message disappears on the top to create an effect like the one in the second image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found a solution. I save the width, height of the message and if is left side or right side in a react state and with this data i render a div with filter: blur();

Comment: It is best practice on S.O. to create an Answer with your solution, and mark it as Accepted, if it is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://cssgradient.io/ to easily generate gradients for your page. You can create a radial gradient there and add it to the background of a chat with a new message using css and html classes which you can add and remove in your javascript code.